# Get only json documents using Marklogic node.js query builder

Tags: marklogic

In my Marklogic DB I have mixed documents formats. And I would like to get only JSON documents from the collection.
I have a query builder statement like this

```
    const documents = await dbClient.documents
        .query(
            qb
                .where(qb.collection('myCollection'))
                .slice(0, 10)
        )
        .result();
```

Is it possible to use some filter here to get only JSON documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not in a position to quickly test the following, but did walk the docs a bit.  Per those docs, you should be able to specify the document format using [.withOptions()](https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#withOptions).  That method's `search` option supports all of [cts:search's options](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search), which includes specifying the document format via "format-FORMAT", or `format-json`, in your case.

```
const documents = await dbClient.documents
    .query(
        qb.where(qb.collection('myCollection'))
          .withOptions({search: ['format-json']})
          .slice(0, 10)
    )
    .result();
```

Comment: It works as expected! Thank you!